# W3C (IIS) logging does not log the ClaimsIdentity username of my WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

My front-end webapplication (MVC) uses a bearer key (SAML) to authenticate itself to the WCF backend serice. The authentication works fine and the ClaimsIdentity object is set properly. However, the username of the ClaimsIdentity does not appear in the W3C IIS logging. Where at the front-end the username is part of the (IIS W3C) log record it does not appear on the WCF service.

*Front-end log record:*

2016-02-02 16:10:24 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx POST /mobile/Tasks/Tasks/ 443 **Wit.329406069** xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+BOIE9;NLNL;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 597 17504 937

*Backend log record:*

2016-02-02 16:10:24 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx POST /services/TaskService.svc - 443 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - 200 0 0 1118 9239 765

The username is missing in the backend logging.

Here is the binding that I use:

```
<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
<binding>
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <message issuedKeyType="BearerKey" establishSecurityContext="false">
      <tokenRequestParameters>
        <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
          <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
          <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
            <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
            <trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
            <trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
          </trust:SecondaryParameters>
        </trust:SecondaryParameters>
      </tokenRequestParameters>
    </message>
  </security>
</binding>
```

Answer (score 1):

IIS is only able to log user names when Windows/basic (and a few others) authentication methods are used.

In your case, IIS uses anonymous authentication, and your application handles the real check. Thus, IIS logs nothing and you have to use your own logging to track the users.

Comment: Is there any way that we can let IIS log the username?

Comment: @KeesdeWit no. That's impossible.